# CSS Background Images

Tags: html, css

Hi there my backgoround images on my webpage are fuzzy and out of focus.

```
body{
    background: url('../images/def2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I'm getting my images from google images so don'y know the reliability of quality.

Comment: Can you post a link to the rest of the page's source code?

Comment: Given just the CSS, Most likely, your image is small - so it is stretched out and low quality.  Could we see def2.jpg?

Comment: sure, actually, that ones a bad example because you're right, the image is too small, but, it's also happening with larger sizes, here's a larger one. http://ink2paper916.deviantart.com/art/Deftones-Chino-Moreno-Be-Quiet-183363948

Comment: That image is small - if you're using it with an HD screen (1920 x 1080) it'll be stretched as hell - not to mention it's a blurry image to begin with.  You're scaling this image up 3 times the size it is originally.

Answer (score 4):

They're probably a lower resolution than your screen, so background-size: cover is stretching them too large.

Answer (score 0):

Too add on to crunch, always make sure your images are large enough!  Stretched images look unprofessional, so remember to always start with the largest file as your source, and make copies as you go when you need to scale it down so you'll always have the large image when you need it.

The reason that images look blurry when scaled up is because they lack the information to display on a larger size.  You can eliminate this need by using vector graphics, but that isn't a feasible solution for a photograph, and is aimed more towards logos and the likes.

If you don't have the original image on hand, try contacting your photographer for the original.  You can scale up if necessary, but anything beyond ~%30 increase will be somewhat visible.

If it's of any use, I did a reverse google image search to find similar images of the same fellow you've shown in higher resolution.  It's not the same photo, as it appears that your picture is a still from a video, but it may be of use.  Just keep in mind that these images are probably copyrighted and not approved for legal usage on your website.